# Bash scripting: permanent pipe

Tags: linux, bash, scripting, pipe, file-descriptor

Here is a script I tried to write:

```
#!/bin/bash

cat <&3 &   # runs in background, takes input from file desc 3
echo "To Terminal"
...
echo "To cat" 1>&3
echo "to cat again" 1>&3
```

Essentially I want my script to spawn a program (in this case, cat) and be able to send input to it through a file descriptor.

This doesn't work ("bad file descriptor"), I think because file descriptors must be associated with a real file. What I need then is to be able to create a **permanent pipe** with an associated descriptor (such as 3) that I can use to write to cat throughout the program. How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
#!/bin/bash
exec 3> >(cat)
echo "To Terminal"
echo "To cat" 1>&3
echo "To cat again" 1>&3
exec 3>&-
```

`cat`, of course, does nothing interesting.  For an example that is still simple but slightly more interesting output, replace `cat` with `awk`:

```
exec 3> >(awk '{print NR,length($0),$0}')
```

Comment: Thank you, it works! But I don't understand how it works. What does this line mean? "exec 3> >(cat)" I understand exec and 3> but could you explain >(cat)?

Comment: The `exec` statement defines the new file descriptor.  The incantation `>(...)` is _process substitution_.  Any output sent to `&3` becomes input to the process.  For more, read about _process substitution_ in `man bash`.

Comment: Excellent...I googled all over but didn't know the term process substitution. Where did you learn all of this? A book, or a website?

Comment: It is in `man bash`.  It even has its own wikipedia page: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_substitution

Comment: I have another question, if you don't mind. I added sleep 3 before the final exec (and chanced "to cat" to "to awk"). To my surprise, the scirpt prints "to terminal", waits 3 seconds, and then the "to awk" prints. Why? Shouldn't the output of the echos go to awk before the program begins to sleep? Thanks.

Comment: I just tested that and I got no such delay.  It is, however, normal to the system to do I/O buffering and I expect that that is the cause of what you are seeing.  There are tools, such as `unbuffer`, to control it.